# Bluemix logging issue to papertrail

Tags: debugging, logging, ibm-cloud, papertrail-app

Any idea why syslog:// protocol from `bluemix` app is not connecting to `PaperTrail` third party logging service?

Here is my process:

[image]

1. create user provided service
2. bind this service
3. restage

then on the papertrail nothing happens:

[image]

You can try it out. The testing app URL is:
http://658.eu-gb.mybluemix.net

Its just Hello world simple nodejs app.

Comment: During Papertrail configuration have you done: Select I use Heroku, enter a name, and click Save?

Comment: Yes, I also did this step, exactly as Jeff is explaining on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhxhFayWUMs

Comment: I did it successfully several times in the past months following: http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/log-management-thirdparty-svc.html?cm_mc_uid=40534881727214328208304&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1447339018

Comment: Notice though that there is a problem in the loggregator (still under investigation) that you might have hit, that random doesn't pass data to Papertrail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the configuration is correct but you are not able to see anything on Papertrail because of a problem with Loggregator component; you should setup an application that iteratively writes on the log to see very few lines arriving.
In order to clear up the status, this is a general problem between Loggregator and logdrain systems (and Papertrail is one of those) and a fix has been testing and will be applied in the next versions of CloudFoundry.

Comment: I'm with Papertrail and strongly suspect that this is the case. Thanks to Riccardo for responding and answering. As he wrote, Bluemix is working on a fix.

If anyone has questions about logging to Papertrail (like because a log sender seems to be configured but logs are not appearing), feel free to email support@papertrailapp.com.

Comment: it was what rspoglia menstioned, so probably cloud foundry bug, but now works! interesting, thanks all!

Comment: The fix has been applied and I confirm that I received positive feedback's from other people that it works.